# delete entries from posting list Lucene 4.0

Tags: lucene, inverted-index

I need to delete entries from posting list. How to do it in Lucene 4.0? I need to do this to test different pruning algorithms.

Thanks in advance

ZP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a good pruning module that you can find here:

http://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-1812

http://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-2632

ZP